# Creating a Term Document Matrix from Text File

Tags: python, matrix, term-document-matrix

I'm trying to read one text file and create a term document matrix using textmining packages. I can create term document matrix where I need to add each line by line. The problem is that I want to include whole file at a time. What am I missing in the following code? Thanks in advance for any suggestion?

```
import textmining

def term_document_matrix_roy_1():

    '''-----------------------------------------'''
    with open("data_set.txt") as f:
        reading_file_line = f.readlines() #entire content, return  list 
        print reading_file_line #list
        reading_file_info = [item.rstrip('\n') for item in reading_file_line]
        print reading_file_info
        print reading_file_info [1] #list-1
        print reading_file_info [2] #list-2

        '''-----------------------------------------'''
        tdm = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix()
        #tdm.add_doc(reading_file_info) #Giving error because of readlines 
        tdm.add_doc(reading_file_info[0])       
        tdm.add_doc(reading_file_info[1])
        tdm.add_doc(reading_file_info[2])


        for row in tdm.rows(cutoff=1):
            print row
```

Sample Text files: "data_set.txt" contain following information:

Lets write some python code

Thus far, this book has mainly discussed the process of ad hoc retrieval.

Along the way we will study some important machine learning techniques.

**Output** will be Term Document Matrix, basically how many times one specific word appear. 
Output Image: http://postimg.org/image/eidddlkld/

[image]

Comment: You didn't really ask a question. What is the output that you are getting? What are you expecting? What doesn't work? What are the error messages?

Comment: As I mention in the question, from the text file each line I'm adding one by one in a array, but how I can add the whole file content. So it read each line by line from the text file and show the term document matrix ? Thanks

Comment: @Burhan Khalid Question is updated now with a image.

Comment: For others working to produce a TDM, I would check out the following tutorial on gensim: http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Fred Thanks for reply. I want to show as it I showed in the image file. Actually the same result I able to produce using following code, but I want each line as separate matrix not one matrix.

```
with open("txt_files/input_data_set.txt") as f:
    reading_file_info = f.read()#reading lines exact content
    reading_file_info=f.read 
    tdm = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix()
    tdm.add_doc(reading_file_info)

    tdm.write_csv('txt_files/input_data_set_result.txt', cutoff=1)
    for row in tdm.rows(cutoff=1):
        print row
```

What I'm trying is reading a text file and create a term document matrix.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're currently adding each line of your file as a separate document.  To add the whole file, you could just concatenate the lines, and add them all at once.

```
tdm = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix()
#tdm.add_doc(reading_file_info) #Giving error because of readlines 
tdm.add_doc(' '.join(reading_file_info))
```

If you are looking for multiple matrices, you'll end up getting only one row in each, as there is only one document, unless you have another way of splitting the line in to separate documents.  You may want to re-think whether this is what you actually want.  Nevertheless, I think this code will do it for you:

```
with open("txt_files/input_data_set.txt") as f:
    tdms = []
    for line in f:
        tdm = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix()
        tdm.add_doc(line.strip())
        tdms.append(tdm)

    for tdm in tdms:
        for row in tdm.rows(cutoff=1):
            print row
```

I haven't really been able to test this code, so the output might not be right. Hopefully it will get you on your way.